# Postgresql column generating

Tags: postgresql

I'm making an application for a company. They needs to divide a total hours to sections. For example they creating a car and they have total 100 hours for a one project. 25 goes to painting 25 goes to montage 25 goes to wheels 25 goes to electronics. This 4 column is standard on table like this and i will have two tables total and finished hours of project:

```
project id -total hours - painting - montage - wheels - electronics
12543      | 100        | 25       | 25      |  25    | 25         |
```

```
project id - hours left - painting - montage - wheels - electronics
12543      | 100        | 25       | 25      |  25    | 25         |
```

but in some cases they want add custom column section on this like sunroof and give there extra hours and open column for this like

```
project id -total hours - painting - montage - wheels - electronics-sunroof
12543      | 125        | 25       | 25      |  25    | 25         | 25
```

But not all projects will have this on their own.

How can i create that elastic numbers of columns and custom columns for each project? Should i divide them to their special different tables or what? And how can i do that operation from an api? Examples are welcome in any language - pseudo code

thanx a lot

Comment: look into pivot and crosstab; for storage use jsonb or EAV

Answer (score 0):

May be you need a project master with details of the projects (including total time), activity master which lists the possible activities and standard duration, and a table which links the projects to activities - i.e. connect all projects to the activities relevant for the project. This table can also capture the time_consumed value.